# How to tell if my fedora 23 server is accepting ipv6 traffic?

Tags: fedora, iptables, ipv6, fedora-23, ip6tables

Short story:

How can I tell if my fedora 23 server is accepting ipv6 traffic?

Longer story:

I want to block external traffic to port 9000 on my godaddy self-managed fedora 23 server. For some reason it doesn't have the expected firewalld (would imagine it's a custom build for godaddy), but it does have iptables, so I set up the appropriate rule in iptables.

However ip6tables does not seem to work, giving the error:
can't initialize ip6tables table `filter'

I have not been able to figure out how to fix this and am wondering if it is disabled deliberately.

Either way, I figure it doesn't matter if my server can't accept ipv6 traffic anyway. Hence my question - how can I tell if my server is accepting ipv6 traffic (if it turns out it's not accepting it, then I can not worry about blocking the port to ipv6 traffic at least for now)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe answering my own question here, but if I do `netstat | grep tcp`, I only get tcp data, nothing that says tcp6, which I believe means that I am not running any services that accept ipv6 traffic.

Answer (score 0):

`ip -6 addr` (or alternatively `ifconfig`) are the commands to display addresses assigned to the interfaces. If there are no globally scoped IPv6 addresses there - there is no need to firewall IPv6 traffic.

Saying the above - Fedora 23 is way out of any support. Do yourself (and others as well) a favor and upgrade to something newer.